# zend framework2 captcha not render - plugin error

Tags: zend-framework2

I've this code in my form

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
        'name' => 'captcha',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Inserisci il codice riportato sotto',
            'captcha' => $this->getCaptchaImage(),
        ),
        'attributes'=>array(
            'id'=>'captcha',
            'tabindex'=>9,
            'class'=>'stylish-text-input span3',
            'required'=>true
        )
    ));
```

for add field

```
public function getCaptchaImage(){
    return $this->captchaImage;
}

private function captchaImage(){
    $this->captchaImage =  new  CaptchaImage(  array(
            'font' =>  $this->currentFontPath,
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 70,
            'dotNoiseLevel' => 20,
            'lineNoiseLevel' => 1,
            'session'=>new container('contact'),
        )
    );
}
```

to generate captcha

in view

```
$this->formRow($form->get('captcha'));
```

i've got

Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Captcha

Answer (score 0):

i solved in this way

```
<?php
$captcha = $form->get("captcha")->getCaptcha();
$captcha->generate();
?>
<img id="captcha-image" width="<?php echo $captcha->getWidth() ?>" height="<?php echo $captcha->getHeight() ?>" src="<?php echo $captcha->getImgUrl() . $captcha->getId() . $captcha->getSuffix(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $captcha->getImgAlt() ?>">
```